# How to use a strongly typed model in React / Typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, jsx

In the code below I would like to use `SubscriptionPlan` as a model for my view.
I can only make JSX work if I cast the data object (the variable `plans` in the code below) to `any`.
How can I make JSX work using the correctly type data object?
Thanks

tsconfig:

```
   "jsx": "react",
```

Component:

```
function Subscriptions() {

    const useFetch = () => {
        var [plans, setPlans] = useState(new Array<SubscriptionPlan>());
        const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

        useAsyncEffect(async (isMounted) => {

            if (!isMounted())
                return;

            plans = await GetSubscriptionPlans(); // API call, returns SubscriptionPlan[]
            setPlans(plans)
            setLoading(false);

        }, []);

        return { plans, loading };
    }

    const { plans, loading } = (useFetch())

    if (loading || plans === null || plans.length == 0)
        return (<div>loading...</div>);

    return (
        <div>
            {plans[0].PlanDescription}              // Does not work.
            {(plans as any)[0].planDescription}     // Works.  Note casing of property name.
        </div>
        )
}
```

Model:

```
export default class SubscriptionPlan {
    public PlanDescription: string = "";  
    //...   
};
```

Comment: Can you explain what doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error it just does not render.

Comment: Properties in javascript are case sensitive. So it looks your `SubscriptionPlan` type is incorrect and should have `planDescription: string` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `planDescription` works, but `PlanDescription` does not, it means that what you are receiving (from what I assume is some server) is not actually what you are getting.

So your types are wrong, or the server is sending the wrong thing.

Comment: That is the problem.  `export const GetSubscriptionPlans = async (): Promise<SubscriptionPlan[]> =>`  One might think this method at some point would return an array of `SubscriptionPlan` objects but no, that signature is just there to make it look good.

Comment: Yea, you probably have an `any` in there somewhere from a JSON.parse